# Javascript - Can't append ip address to "GET" url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, web

Everything gets appended to the url except for the ip address. The end of the url should look like this for example; ip=127.0.0.1. But the ip address is not being added. Any ideas?

Here is the code...

```
<!-- User-Agent IP Code -->
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {
    $.get( "https://hook.us1.make.com/s86ki3rt515ieg1gr3f9xxc5ufdu59zb?" +location.search.substring(1), "user=" + navigator.userAgent, "ip=" + json.ip);
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
<!-- User-Agent IP Code -->
```

Comment: why are you using the jsonp representation? cant you just use it without format? `fetch("https://api.ipify.org").then(e => e.text().then(e => console.log(e)))` or with jquery `$.get("https://api.ipify.org", e => console.log(e))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the "$.get" line. I looks like your trying to concatenate the parameters in the string and they aren't properly formatted. In the $.get() function it expects the params to be a single object. You can create an object with the params and put it in the function. I'm not sure how the navigator.userAgent or json.ip string is from the code you have provided but if you pass the params it should give you a good idea. Here is my code.

```
<!-- User-Agent IP Code -->
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {
    let params = {
        user: navigator.userAgent,
        ip: json.ip
    };

    $.get("https://hook.us1.make.com/s86ki3rt515ieg1gr3f9xxc5ufdu59zb", params);
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
<!-- User-Agent IP Code -->
```

Comment: Seems to work great, but it's missing the: +location.search.substring(1). When added it seems to break your code.

Comment: I had to add the +location.search.substring(1) to your code, but was able to get everything working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to construct the query string.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
params.append('user', navigator.userAgent);
params.append('ip', json.ip);
$.get("https://hook.us1.make.com/s86ki3rt515ieg1gr3f9xxc5ufdu59zb?" + params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few syntax issues. I made some adjustments and wrapped your endpoint using the [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) method, which can prevent the URI-unfriendly characters from breaking the formattings.

```
     $.get(encodeURI(
      "https://hook.us1.make.com/s86ki3rt515ieg1gr3f9xxc5ufdu59zb" +
        location.search.substring(1) +
        "?user=" +
        navigator.userAgent +
        "&ip=" +
        json.ip
    ));
```